# Medir tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c++, c++11

Como puedo medir el tiempo de ejecución de una función? Probé con esta solución pero a veces me da 0 en el tiempo transcurrido.
Como medís el tiempo cuando queréis saber la eficiencia de un código?

```
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    funcion_trabajosa();
    auto end= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end- start;
    std::cout << "tiempo transcurrido: " << elapsed.count() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Si el tiempo es más breve que la resolución del reloj una técnica típica consiste en ejecutar la función muchas veces, cronometrando el tiempo total, y después dividir por el número de ejecuciones.

Comment: prueba a verlo en nanosegundos `auto elepsed_time_ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end - start).count();`